# How to format big int values in Activescaffold plugin rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold

I am using rails 3 activesacaffold plugin for my admin pannel. I have a table which has big int values.

When I list the values its showing as '62,175,049,070'. How can I format this to show like '62175049070'. Since we are using activescaffold plugin we dont have any direct view pages to make modification.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delimiter option:

```
active scaffold :model do
  ...
  conf.columns[:ndc].options = {:i18n_number => {:delimiter => ''}}
  ...
end
```

https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API:-Column